# How do msn like apps work in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, msn-messenger

How is the msn messenger app developed? What I want to know is how does the app gets ti know that a new message is received, even while running in the background. Please refer any code snippets or tutorial. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Probably with push notification.
See [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)